# Why UITableView Delegate methods are called only single time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement tab bar controller in my app with UITableView.I have three tab items.And this is the screenshot of [Product Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv4yI.png). I am adding my product to mycart. And after adding two products in my cart this is my [MyCart Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mMo.png). But after going back to Product Tab and removing or adding any product and returning to the MyCart Tab then it is unchanged. I loaded all my data in viewWillAppear() method. Using breakpoints i found that my UITableView delegate methods are called only one time not every time I changing my tab items.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    handler = [delegate getHandler];

    allProducts = [handler getAllProducts];

   }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    productDataModel = [allProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    addToCartFlagNumber = (NSNumber*)productDataModel.productAvailability;

    if([addToCartFlagNumber integerValue]){

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProductListTableViewCell";
        ProductListTableViewCell *cell = (ProductListTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        cell.productListNameLabel.text = productDataModel.productName;
        cell.productListImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:productDataModel.productImageName];
        cell.productListDescriptionLabel.text = productDataModel.productDescription;
        cell.addToCartButton.tagValue = [productDataModel.productID integerValue];
        cell.addToCartButton.flagValue = 0;


        return cell;
    }

    else{
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"UpcomingProductListTableViewCell";
        UpcomingProductListTableViewCell *cell = (UpcomingProductListTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


        cell.productListNameLabel.text = productDataModel.productName;
        cell.productListImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:productDataModel.productImageName];
        cell.productListDescriptionLabel.text = productDataModel.productDescription;

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you reloadedtable in view will appear ?

Comment: @saurabhgoyal no.Ok I am trying it.

Comment: Post the code which you have tried so far

Comment: solved!!!
I didn't take any IBOutlet UITableView in my .h file. Thats why I coudln't find my tableView to reload. And now reloaded my tableView in viewWillAppear also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in viewWillAppear method of viewController in all three tab.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```